# clone an hg directory from a particular date

Tags: mercurial

Is there a way to get a copy of a hg repository as it was at a particular date?

For example, in subversion I would use:

```
svn checkout -r {2012-04-04} ...
```

And it would check out a revision as it appeared on the fourth of April.

In git its a little more complicated, but can be done:

```
git checkout `git rev-list -n 1 --before="2012-04-04" master`
```

Can you do the same thing in hg?

Comment: with git you can do `git checkout master@{2.days.ago}` or `git checkout master@{2012-04-04}`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

(**EDIT:** My love of revsets has caused me to overlook the obvious answer: `hg update --date 2012-04-04` should get you the tipmost revision as of that date.)

If you have the whole repository cloned already (date specifications don't seem to work with `clone`), you can do

```
hg update --rev "date('< 2012-04-04')"
```

If there's a possibility that the repository had multiple heads/branches at the date you want, you'll have to AND in some more conditions to narrow it down to the right changeset:

```
hg update --rev "date('< 2012-04-04') and branch(v1.1)"
```

Check out `hg help revsets` and `hg help dates` for more information.

Later, if you want to go back to the tip, just

```
hg update
```

Comment: Thanks-- that explains why I was have trouble finding it, I was looking for a solution with hg clone

Comment: So, apparently if you're starting from nothing, you need to first 'clone' the repository, which gives you the latest, and then "downgrade" it by invoking 'update' to a previous version.  Kind of weird.